# Plot a well known double well surface

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a well known energy landscape from physics, the Muller Brown potential.
Taken from the literature (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01241):
[image]
[image]
[image: The authors' plot:]

With my contour plot, however, I cannot see the two wells, it looks as if it was just a single Gaussian.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mp

# Parameters of Muller Brown Potential (cf. Bonfati & Cob 2017)
A = np.array([-200, -100, -170, 15])
a = np.array([-1, -1, -6.5, 0.7])
b = np.array([0, 0, 11, 0.6])
c = np.array([-10, -10, -6.5, 0.7])
x_m = np.array([1, 0, -0.5, -1])
y_m = np.array([0, 0.5, 1.5, 1])

x = np.linspace(-1.5, 1, 1000)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 2, 1000)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)


Z =A[0]*np.exp( a[0]*(XX-x_m[0])**2 + b[0]*(XX-x_m[0])*(YY-y_m[0]) + c[0]*(YY-y_m[0])**2 )
+  A[1]*np.exp( a[1]*(XX-x_m[1])**2 + b[1]*(XX-x_m[1])*(YY-y_m[1]) + c[1]*(YY-y_m[1])**2 )
+  A[2]*np.exp( a[2]*(XX-x_m[2])**2 + b[2]*(XX-x_m[2])*(YY-y_m[2]) + c[2]*(YY-y_m[2])**2 )
+  A[3]*np.exp( a[3]*(XX-x_m[3])**2 + b[3]*(XX-x_m[3])*(YY-y_m[3]) + c[3]*(YY-y_m[3])**2 )



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

c=ax.contourf(XX, YY, Z)
plt.colorbar(c)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

[image]

**edit:** Setting the limits of the plot region to the ones the authors does not seem to help.
If I use

```
x = np.linspace(-2, 0, 1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
```

I see this:
[image]

Comment: Your limits are not quite right for one thing

Comment: If I choose the limits form the original image, my plot is not fully visible. As if they were using a bias or something.

Comment: You can set the limits via the appropriate linspace bounds

Comment: see the edit, it does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parantheses around the expression for `Z` so that you effectively evaluated only the first summand.

```
x = np.linspace(-1.5, 0.2, 1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 1.9, 1000)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = (A[0]*np.exp( a[0]*(XX-x_m[0])**2 + b[0]*(XX-x_m[0])*(YY-y_m[0]) + c[0]*(YY-y_m[0])**2 )
    +A[1]*np.exp( a[1]*(XX-x_m[1])**2 + b[1]*(XX-x_m[1])*(YY-y_m[1]) + c[1]*(YY-y_m[1])**2 )
    +A[2]*np.exp( a[2]*(XX-x_m[2])**2 + b[2]*(XX-x_m[2])*(YY-y_m[2]) + c[2]*(YY-y_m[2])**2 )
    +A[3]*np.exp( a[3]*(XX-x_m[3])**2 + b[3]*(XX-x_m[3])*(YY-y_m[3]) + c[3]*(YY-y_m[3])**2 ))
```

[Bonus](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0021782419300777):

```
m1 = (-0.558223634633024, 1.441725841804669)
m2 = (-0.050010822998206, 0.466694104871972)
s1 = (-0.822001558732732, 0.624312802814871)
plt.plot(*m1, 'm*'), plt.text(*m1, "  Min 1")
plt.plot(*m2, 'm*'), plt.text(*m2, "  Min 2")
plt.plot(*s1, 'bo'), plt.text(*s1, "  Saddle 1")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Stef!!! I did not know that this was a thing. Strange that the line breaks stop the parsing of the equation.

Comment: for reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure, esp. sections 2.1.5 and 2.1.6 ([PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) recommends parantheses)